# Using Html.DropDownListFor() with a SelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the correct way to populate a SelectList when using the Html.DropDownListFor helper in ASP.Net MVC 3?

I basically have a "Create" form which I want to specify the entry values on for a particular field.  For example, it is a movie database and I want the ability to enter a Genre, but I don't want users to be able to enter what they like, so I assume a SelectList to be the best answer?

A way that works is to create a new class with a static method to return the SelectList:

```
public class Genres
{
    public static List<string> GetGenres()
    {
        List<string> myGenres = new List<string>();
        myGenres.Add("Comedy");
        myGenres.Add("Romantic Comedy");
        myGenres.Add("Sci-Fi");
        myGenres.Add("Horror");

        return myGenres;
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, new SelectList(OLL.Models.Genres.GetGenres()))
    </div>
```

It just doesn't seem like the right/easiest way to do it?  I think I'm missing something obvious here...

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: This looks like a fine solution to me.  Perhaps you could factor out the `new SelectList` code into another method, but I don't see a problem with your current code.

Comment: I think I'm going to create a generic model class which then has static IEnumerables for each field I need to do this with.  For example, `public static IEnumerable<string> Genres = new List<string> { "Action", "Adventure", "Animation" };`

Comment: Perhaps this thread will help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740419/dropdownlistfor-model-binding

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple selectList style I use for drop downs all the time, hopefully you find this helpeful.

```
 ViewBag.AlbumListDD = from c in db.Query<DatabaseEntities.VenuePhotoAlbum>("WHERE VenueId = @0", VenueId)
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                         Text = c.Name,
                         Value = c.Id.ToString()
                      };
```

Inside my view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AlbumId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AlbumListDD, new { id = "ChangeAlbum" })
```

Hopefully you can find this useful as this is a database route to go. I typically like to have all of that sort of information in a database and that way users can dynamically add/remove and change these dropdown items at will. There is a bit of SQL work behind the scenes required when removing a type but it has proven to be very successful and fast for me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var og = (from s in DB.Products
 select new SelectListItem
  {
        Text = s.ProductName,
         Value = s.ProductID.ToString()
  }); 
  ViewBag.lstProducts = new SelectList(getproductname, "ProductID", "ProductName");
<p>
    @Html.DropDownList("AlbumId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lstProducts, new { @id = "drp" });
</p>
```