# DropDownListFor - Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My first MVC project and have ran into an issue which I hope someone can assist with.

Basically I have a DropDownListFor object which I want to populate with a list of available times for the user to pick from and store the selected item in an attribute for later consumption.

The below is producing a null value error so I'm missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have:

**Controller:**

```
private MyModelObject m_model = new MyModelObject();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var AvailTimes = new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new {Value="00:00",Text="12:00 AM"},
        new {Value="00:30",Text="12:30 AM"},
        new {Value="01:00",Text="1:00 AM"},
        new {Value="22:30",Text="10:30 PM"},
        new {Value="23:00",Text="11:00 PM"},
        new {Value="23:30",Text="11:30 PM"},                 
    }); 
    return View(m_model);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyModelObject
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectList> AvailTimes { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartTime, 
                       new SelectList(model.AvailTimes, "Value", "Text"))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't make your model a private variable to the controller. Each time a request is sent a new controller instance will be created so don't think that you will be able to reuse it between actions. Also you don't seem to be doing anything useful with the `AvailTimes` local variable that you declared in your action and it is subject to a fast garbage collection. Also your model is incorrect. The `AvailTimes` property must be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and not `IEnumerable<SelectList>`.

Let's start by fixing the view model first:

```
public class MyModelObject
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailTimes { get; set; }
}
```

then the controller action which will feed the view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = MyModelObject
    {
        AvailTimes = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "00:00", Text = "12:00 AM" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "00:30", Text = "12:30 AM" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "01:00", Text = "1:00 AM" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "22:30", Text = "10:30 PM" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "23:00", Text = "11:00 PM" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "23:30", Text = "11:30 PM" },                 
         } 
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally the strongly typed view:

```
@model MyModelObject
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StartTime, Model.AvailTimes)
```

You also have the possibility to assign those available hours in your view model directly:

```
public class MyModelObject
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailTimes 
    { 
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "00:00", Text = "12:00 AM" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "00:30", Text = "12:30 AM" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "01:00", Text = "1:00 AM" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "22:30", Text = "10:30 PM" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "23:00", Text = "11:00 PM" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "23:30", Text = "11:30 PM" },                 
             }; 
        }
    }
}
```

Now your controller action could become:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = MyModelObject();
    return View(model);
}
```

and the view obviously stays unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Darin, your reply was not only helpful but very informative.

Answer (score 0):

The value of Model.AvailTimes is never assigned, therefore is null by default.