# List Items in the DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a List and i want to populate this list in a dropdownbox.

FROM CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> hum = allHuman();
            return View();

        }
```

FROM VIEW :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( ..... // NOW HOW CAN I DISPLAY THE VALUES IN THE DROPDOWNLIST ?
```

Comment: As @Xander, pointed out, you can do this yourself. read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885627/using-html-dropdownlistfor-with-a-selectlist Viewbag is an example. But you will still want to pass a model back to your View and bind the dropdownlistfor to it

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
var list = new SelectList(allHuman(), "Id", "Name");
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownList("humans", Model as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a model type first.

```
class MyViewModel
{
    // I assume you will use this property to read the selected value 
    public string Human {get;set;}

    //dropdown values
    public List<SelectListItem> AllHumans {get;set;}
}
```

Then create an instance in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { AllHumans  =  allHuman()};
    return View(model);
}
```

Then you can display it in your view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Human, Model.AllHumans, null)
```